# How to find fragment in backstack to navigate to and don't recreate it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using navigation component. My main fragment is opening as default. When i'm navigating to another fragment in my bottom navigation i can click on a recycler view item and it should navigate me back to my main fragment and send arguments. The problem is that it's recreating my main fragment, so my viewmodel of this main fragment recreats too. I'm using this method to navigate by clicking on item:

```
findNavController().navigate(NavGraphDirections.actionGlobalMainFragment(schemeId))
```

Can i find this fragment in backstack somehow? (because it's in it) and navigate to it without recreating with sending argument?

Comment: Are you using Navigation 2.4 and its [built-in support for multiple back stacks](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f)? That will automatically save and then restore the state of each bottom navigation tab.

Comment: Yes. It's v. 2.4.0-beta02 in my project

Comment: @ianhanniballake maybe it's because i'm sending argument? So that's why it's recreating?

Comment: If you are using `setupWithNavController()`, then you are using multiple back stacks. Manually calling `navigate()` is not going to do what you want (it is going to navigate you to a brand new destination). So it sounds like you aren't actually using multiple back stacks at all. You'll need to explain what you're trying to do with arguments though - bottom navigation destinations generally don't take arguments (given that they are global destinations reachable from anywhere); it doesn't seem like arguments are what you want to be using for your use case.

Comment: @ianhanniballake i'm using `setupWithNavController()` in my MainActivity. I'm sending id of my item by arguments to my main fragment and work with it in it. So how can i send it in other way?

Comment: @ianhanniballake in my nav graph i have fragment which is main and 3 included nav xmls for tabs in bottom navigation. main frag have global action and argument (id)

Comment: @ianhanniballake and i'm using safeArgs

Comment: @ianhanniballake just to be clear. When i switch between bottom nav tabs it's ok my instances are saved. My main frag is map. My next frag in tab it's recycler view with tileOverlay items. When i click on item i want to navigate to my main fram which is map, send argument which is id of item so i can use this id in my main frag to take row from Room and use it to locate to this tileOverlay on my map. I'm using `findNavController().navigate(*navDirections(argument blah blah)*)` and then my main argument run OnCreate again but my map still in backstack :(